# Syntax error when using Spring @ConditionalOnExpression in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, spring-annotations, spring-expression-language

I import in a Kotlin configuration class the

> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnExpression

but I get the error message of `An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant` from IntelliJ when I use the annotation with Spring expression language on a bean definition

> @ConditionalOnExpression("${xxx.enabled:true} or ${yyy.enabled:true}")

The xxx.enabled and yyy.enabled are configured in a yml file.

What could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: You might need to escape the annotation to `@ConditionalOnExpression("\${xxx.enabled:true} or \${yyy.enabled:true}")`

Comment: @MarkAbersold Please have this as an answer and I will pick it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kotlin, the `$` operator is used for string interpolation. When your annotation contains `@ConditionalOnExpression("${xxx.enabled:true} or ${yyy.enabled:true}")` it tries to interpolate whatever is in the curly braces into your string - this makes the string not a compile-time constant. You need to escape the `$` to tell the Kotlin compiler not to treat that as an interpolated String. Spring will inject the values into the annotation at run time.

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("\${xxx.enabled:true} or \${yyy.enabled:true}")
```